# Switch between two windows in C# (ChromeDriver and c# application)

Tags: c#, windows, selenium-webdriver

I would like to switch between two windows in C#. I can switch between the two windows when the focus is on one page but not on the other with SwitchToThisWindow(). The application flashes but does not come to the foreground. How is it possible that when I have the focus (press on the window) it works but not with the other? I use Selenium and ChromeDriver for the second window.

I use a translator, sorry for the formulations

Here is an extract of the code: (I made a loop but it is not clean)

```
public IWebDriver driver;
Process[] nbr1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("App1"); // C# application
Process[] nbr2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("App2"); // HMI with google chrome

if (IsForegroundProcess(nbr1[0].Id))
  foreach(var process in nbr2) {
    //SetFocus(process.MainWindowHandle);
    //SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
    SwitchToThisWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, true);
  }
//actions.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab).KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt).Perform();

else {
  SetForegroundWindow(nbr1[0].MainWindowHandle);

  do {
    SetFocus(nbr1[0].MainWindowHandle);

    SwitchToThisWindow(nbr1[0].MainWindowHandle, true);
    cpt++;

    if (cpt > 100) break;
  } while (!IsForegroundProcess(nbr1[0].Id));
}
```